# file transfer between server and client input stream

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I'm working on a java server-client based file transfer over socket project, I'll sum up the project shortly, I have text files related to server and client, server related text contains which ports are going to be opened and client text contains the IP and port to be connected on(server side is like 4444 and client side is like 4444 localhost) The file transfer on a single client is running pretty ok, now I'm working on second client connection and transfer, what I'm trying to do is; when a second client is run, it will read the first line of the text file (which is already in use by the first client), I thought a recursion will solve the problem but seems I couldn't figure out what I've done wrong, below are the code snippet from client side

```
boolean connected = false;
private void connection() {
    while (!connected) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("c_input.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            String delims = "[ ]";
            String[] elements = new String[8];
            elements = line.split(delims);
            serverPort = Integer.parseInt(elements[portIndex]);
            hostIP = elements[ipIndex];
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostIP, serverPort);
            is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

            if (is != null) {
                connected = true;
                System.out.println("connected to " + hostIP + " from port "
                        + serverPort);
                br.close();
                fr.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("The port " + serverPort
                        + " is occupied, now trying another port.");
                portIndex = portIndex + 2;
                ipIndex = ipIndex + 2;
                connection();
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I used recursion there, because if a port is bound by another client it has to read another line from text file and split and retry connection with the new line's inputs.(in terms short the whole method will run again) But when it comes to running, the first client connects and when second one tries to connect from same port with client1 the code still gets in if loop instead of getting in else block (I get the message from the if check's `println` on the console and by the way `is` in the if check stands for InputStream) which means there is a stream coming from server, is this normal? if so how can I achieve the whole thing connection method does all over again if the port is bound by another client?

Comment: I didnt get what you want to say. Please be more clear.

Comment: ok, which part you want me to clarify please, my aim or what I did?

Comment: Is your all port mention in a file open for client connection?

Comment: ok thank you, the problem is if a port is bound I need to run the whole `connection` method again, but there is an InputStream coming to client2 which skips my else block and still gets in the if block (although it only prints the line but the connection on server is not trully established) what I'm trying is if a port is bound, the code should simply re-run the connection method again but I couldn't manage my code to get in else block

Comment: server and client uses distinct text files to perform their operations